# test class coverage for return statement

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage, code

How do i cover code coverage for a return statement.I am not using pagereference.

```
if(atleastoneselected==false){
            errMsg='No contacts Selected';//not covered
            return page.importfile;//not covered
        }
        if(smstoggle==false && Emailtoggle==false){
            errMsg='Select the required toggle'; //not covered
            return page.importfile;//not covered
        }
        if(smstoggle|| Emailtoggle){//covered
            sucmsg=null;        //covered      
        }
        if( smstoggle && Emailtoggle){       
              sucmsg=null;//not covered
        }
```

Comment: Please update your question with more details,  Where did you get stuck? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am a noob here in coding test class,i have tried pagereference examples given in sfdc community.I am stuck in return statement.

Comment: @Maneesh,How did you resolved this

Comment: @Shiv I changed the main class.sry man i don't remember the changes I made .It was a long time ago.

Answer (score 2):

Basically you need to call your function multiple times, each time with slightly different parameters or data so that the code enters each `if` statement.
As you can see, your code ran once with `smstoggle = true`, and so covered that code.
You need to run it again with all possible permutations of your code:

- `atleastoneselected == false`
- `smstoggle==false && Emailtoggle==false`
- `smstoggle && Emailtoggle`

Comment: I tried it ,it's not covering,the issue is my test class is not covering any if conditions.

Comment: It would help if you would share your code.

Comment: If your `if` conditions aren't being covered, you're not tailoring your test data correctly as @AvailableName says. The only way to obtain code coverage is to execute the code.